# MPEG-Dash - "moof" length in Segment Templates

Tags: mpeg-dash

Specific question related to the DASH Standard.

A "moof" is followed by "mdat" in MPEG-DASH standard in Segment Templates.

For ex
Segment 1 - duration 2 seconds -  moof + mdat
Segment 2 - duration 2 seconds -  moof + mdat

Is the "moof" length across segments a constant?  Can this be considered a constant to arrive at the mdat offset in subsequent segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not assume the "moof" length to be constant across segments - it could be, but it does not necessarily have to be.

Why would you assume this? The "moof", like each box in an MP4 file, contains the box size at the very beginning of a box, which you can easily parse.

What do you want to achieve?